# body element moving when there is absolute positioning

Tags: css, css-position

I have a really strange quirk happening on a site that I am building. Its a theme for concrete5 but the html is pretty site is here http://wtms.onbutton.co.uk/mm.

If you look the `body` has dropped by about 100px as if there is a margin. If I remove the section element, nothing is affected and the header renders fine.

Can anyone explain what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: I think its happening only on firefox. right??

Comment: no im getting the same thing with chrome and ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by specifying `display: inline-block` for your section element.

i.e.

```
section {
    display: inline-block; /* new */
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You diamond! What causes that then, I've never had that happened before?

Comment: Probably because by definition a block level element (div, section etc..) is rendered in such a way that it forces a new line before and after itself. Still, such a gap is unexplainable!

Comment: if you are happy with this response, please check it as answered so other people don't continue to work on this for you.